# How to draw a path by using longitiude and latitude in Windows Form Application c#?

Tags: c#, gps, location, drawing, picturebox

I can collect longitude and latitude info from GNGGA data get from GPS/GNSS board, but I can't draw a path according to longitude and latitude information. 
[For example you can see in picture;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owQhQ.png)

In pıcture there is a also direction.For the first step direction is not important. I just want to draw it wiht points or lines without direction(if it is possible).To be trust, I tried to draw in chart and picture box but I couldn't achieve it.
Have you got any ideas about it?
Here is my code; gBoylam=longitude, gEnlem=lattitude, gYukseklik=altitude

```
 gParca=NMEA.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        switch (gParca[0])
        {
            //Global Positioning System Fix data
            case "$GNGGA":
                gParca[2] = gParca[2].Replace('.', ',');
                gParca[4] = gParca[4].Replace('.', ',');
                if (gParca[3]=="N")
                {
                    gKG = "North";
                }
                else if(gParca[3]=="S")
                {
                    gKG = "South";
                }
                if (gParca[5]=="E")
                {
                    gDB = "East";
                }
                else if(gParca[5]=="W")
                {
                    gDB = "West";
                }
            switch (gParca[6])
                {
                    case "0": gKilitlenme = "Invalid"; break;
                    case "1": gKilitlenme = "GPS fix (SPS)"; break;
                    case "2": gKilitlenme = "DGPS fix"; break;
                    case "3": gKilitlenme = "PPS fix"; break;
                    case "4": gKilitlenme = "RTK fix"; break;
                    case "5": gKilitlenme = "RTK float"; break;
                    case "6": gKilitlenme = "Estimated"; break;
                    case "7": gKilitlenme = "Manuel Input"; break;
                    case "8": gKilitlenme = "Simulation"; break;
                    default: gKilitlenme = "Unknown"; break;
                }
            gEnlem = gParca[2];
            gBoylam = gParca[4];
            gUydular = gParca[7];
            gYukseklik = gParca[9] + " " + gParca[10];
           // gVeriTipi = "GPS Data Fix";
            gSaat = gParca[1].Substring(0, 2) + ":" + gParca[1].Substring(2, 2) + " " +
                gParca[1].Substring(4, 2) + " (UTF)";
            gYataySapma = gParca[8];
            GPSData(NMEA);
            break;
            default:
            break;

        }
        txtbxLongitude.Text = gBoylam + " " + gDB;
        txtbxLatitude.Text = gEnlem + " " + gKG;
        txtbxAltitude.Text = gYukseklik;
        txtbxFixQuality.Text = gKilitlenme;
        txtbxSatellites.Text = gUydular;
        txtbxTime.Text = gSaat;
```

Comment: I don't see a connection between what you're trying to do and your code.

Comment: In fact, this is why I am here. I don' t know how to start. I tried to do this in picture box and chart(graphics) but I couldn't do it for example;
    
  

           System.Drawing.Point[] pathx= new 
           System.Drawing.Point[Convert.ToInt16(gEnlem)];

      System.Drawing.Point[] pathy = new 
             System.Drawing.Point[Convert.ToInt16(gBoylam)];
           g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
           g.DrawPolygon(pen1, pathx);
           g.DrawPath(pen1, pathy);
           chartPath.Series["GPS"].Points.AddXY(gBoylam, gEnlem);